# Typescript intellisense without emitting require

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, reactjs

My HTML contains this:

```
<script src="js/vendor/react.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/react-dom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-react-component.js"></script>
```

...and I'm trying to write a simple TSX file, in Visual Studio 2015, to be transpiled into `my-react-component.js`:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

class ExampleApplication extends React.Component<any, {}> {
  render() {
      return <p>{this.props.message}</p>;
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <ExampleApplication message="Hello, world" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I already imported the `react.d.ts` and `react-dom.d.ts` from *DefinitelyTyped* and included them in my `tsd.d.ts`

The problem is: TypeScript will not recognize "React" and "ReactDOM" unless I explicitly import them, with:

```
import * as React from "react"; 
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

And that works fine for editing the .tsx (in fact I get full IntelliSense for those namespaces).

But the transpiled .js - using the "React" JSX compilation option - includes the unwanted *requires*:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
```

Which cause an error on the page execution, because both React, and ReactDOM are global names defined by react.js and there is no "require" function available.

Isn't there a way to declare those names to TypeScript, without emitting the actual require for each of them?

Otherwise - what is wrong in what I'm trying to do? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't there a way to declare those names to TypeScript, without emiting the actual require for each of them?

There is. Use the *global* versions of the TypeScript definitions : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react-global.d.ts

> Otherwise - what is wrong in what I'm trying to do? What am I mising?

Using *global modules* is a bad idea. You will run into issues as soon as you scale to about 50 files (happens very quickly) https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: Thanks a lot, @basarat ! That fixed it.

About the global modules being a bad idea, you are absolutely right. 

However, I'm currently evaluating the VS 2015 / TypeScript / TSX ecosystem and wanted to make sure that certain common scenarios would be handled by the tool. Thanks again.